# How to send a mail here?

Tags: discussion, private-messages

How to send a mail to a person here?
I really don't know where can I find information about it.
It can help to solve my problem [Prove the polynomial ring and algebra of quaternions isomorphisms](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2561756/prove-the-polynomial-ring-and-algebra-of-quaternions-isomorphisms).

Comment: You can only send mail to users here if they give out their e-mail address, e.g. by putting it in their profile. Without having done anything to verify it, I'm guessing that is extremely rare.

Comment: Hi please ask this in meta instead.

Comment: Thanks for answer!

Comment: Don't. Unsolicited e-mail is one of the best ways of annoying someone who you think could help you. Only send e-mail if the recipient approves of it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I have received one email from math.SE (it is not hard to find my email). It was someone demanding to know why I voted to close a question. I did not respond. I would respond to most emails, given that the emails are written in good faith and worth my time.

To answer your question of "how to send mail" - the answer is that if someone has their email on their profile <strike>(or it is easily findable)</strike> and your email is written in good faith and not a waste of their time, then you may send an email. In all other cases don't. There is no private messaging feature (other than maybe creating a chat) for a reason.

This is a question and answer site, not a discussion forum. Rarely should you have a need to email someone and even more rarely is it worth their time.

Comment: I would say that if someone doesn't put their email (or a link to their website) on their profile, chances are they don't want emails related to Math.SE, even if their email is easily found.

Comment: @Jyrki Lahtonen IMO these comments should be summarized and put on a page for new users.