# How do I contact the poster of a deleted answer?

Tags: support

Poster A gave an upvoted and accepted answer to a question. Poster B also answered the question, but then deleted his answer—perhaps after a quick glance at A's short and simple answer, considering that his own was no improvement. However, A's answer was wrong while B's (deleted) answer was right. I would like to point this out to B. How can I do this?

Comment: Since you have $>10k$ rep you can see his username so perhaps an option would be to leave a comment under one of their question/answer explaining the situation? (preferably an older post so that other users won't get bothered by seeing off-topic comments).

Comment: Somewhat related: [How do I contact other users?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/57537) (on [meta.se]) and [How to *contact* a specific user? / Is there any sort of PM (private message) facility available?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3129) (on this meta).

Answer (score 9):

If you know that user B routinely hangs out in chatroom C, you can drop in there and tell them about it.

If user B doesn't chat much (or not at all): abusing the comment system for such purposes tends to be tolerated (it would be nice if you clean up yourselves after the matter has been settled). Within reason. If B declines or doesn't react, don't pester them.

Generally, more important than notifying B is to notify A and the question author. (Here done, resp. not applicable.) If A fixes their answer, all is well in that regard. Especially when the account of the question author no longer exists, so the accept mark cannot be given to a different answer, that is highly desirable.

Comment: I have already followed Nyassa's suggestion above. Prior to this, I notified A in a comment to her answer, but she has not responded so far. I will delete my off-topic comment on B's old post if I get an acknowledgement of it. I leave it to the good will of A and/or B to ensure that the OP is informed.

Comment: I know that you already notified A (it's public information, visible to all who look), and informing the OP isn't possible (unless someone knows them personally) because the account is deleted. [That's what the (done/not applicable) parenthetical is about.] Nice of you that you'll clean up yourself. Let's hope A fixes their answer, it's not pleasant to have an incorrect answer accepted.

Comment: I didn't realize that you had identified the post, or that the OP had deleted her account. (Now I notice the grey background of her usernumber and get its meaning.)

Comment: Unfortunately there is no response from A, B, or the OP. The question is like "what is the sum of $2$ and $2$"? Poster A answers $5$, an answer which is upvoted by viewers and accepted by the (transient) OP. If someone then edits A's answer, changing the $5$ to $4$, it is no longer the answer that A gave nor the answer that bore the upvotes and acceptance. So I won't do that. What I have done put up my own answer ($4$).

Comment: That's good, @JohnBentin. Thanks.